# htaccess file not recognizing a space in: AddType application/x-httpd-php html

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am creating a `CMS` that allows admin to manage the `.htaccess` from administration. The script handles numerous aspects of the `.htaccess` file with everything working correctly except: `AddType application/x-httpd-php html`

The script writes the code correctly except it is not recognizing the space between `AddType application/x-httpd-php` and `html`

If after the script writes the code I delete the space and add it directly in with my space bar the `.htaccess` file works perfectly... at a total loss.

This is the code which writes that portion of the file:

```
# process as php
    if($process_as_php == 1){$htaccess_code .= "# Allows files to process php \r";      
        $htaccess_code .= "AddType application/x-httpd-php html";
    $htaccess_code .= " \r";    
    }
```

This is how the file is saved:

```
$file_handle = fopen($level.'.htaccess', 'w');      
    fwrite($file_handle, $htaccess_code);
    fclose($file_handle);
```

Any assistance would be appreciated
Pete

Comment: Did you perhaps copy `AddType application/x-httpd-php html` from an external resource in to your script? That's the only thing I can think of. Though, I'm sure you would have manually removed the space in your script and inserted it manually... If that's the case, I'd be at a total loss too.

Comment: I had cut and pasted it in so I went back and manually typed it in but to no avail. Thanks for the input though

Comment: How are you writing/saving the file?

Comment: I updated the question to show the code used to save the file

Comment: Does it make any difference if you try using `file_put_contents`? Also, perhaps try on another server to see if the issue persists.

Comment: I had file_put_contents and it conflicted with another aspect... I haven't uploaded to the net yet... I had thought to try it up there but won't get to that phase for a day or two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered here:

[Script to write htaccess file adding phantom unknown character causing a 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028293/script-to-write-htaccess-file-adding-phantom-unknown-character-causing-a-500-err)

While the circumstances were different, it cause was the same and the soulution likewise was the same.