# Script to write htaccess file adding phantom unknown character causing a 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am writing a widget that allows admin to manage the `htaccess file` from administration. The script is adding a phantom character rendered as a space in the `htaccess code` being generated which is throwing a 500 error.

## HERE IS THE CODE:

```
# block/allow users by ip
    if(!empty($block_ips) || !empty($allowed_ips)){
    $htaccess_code .= "#Block-Allow users by IP \r\n";
    $htaccess_code .= "order allow,deny \r\n";
    }   
    if(!empty($block_ips)){
    $the_ips = explode(',',$block_ips);
        foreach($the_ips as $the_ip){ $htaccess_code .= "deny from ".trim($the_ip)." \r\n"; }
    }   
    if(!empty($allowed_ips)){
    $the_ips = explode(',',$allowed_ips);
        foreach($the_ips as $the_ip){ $htaccess_code .= "allow from ".trim($the_ip)." \r\n"; }
        }   
    $htaccess_code .= "allow from all \r\n";
    $htaccess_code .= " \r\n";
```

## WHICH PRODUCES:

```
#Block-Allow users by IP 
    order allow,deny 
    deny from 000.000.111.111 
    deny from 444.444.555.555 
    allow from 444.433.555.555 
    allow from 010.000.111.111 
    allow from all
```

There is a space/phantom character at the end of each line. If during the 500 error I delete the space editing live through FTP and save the `htaccess file` and then refresh the page all id fine.

If I remove the space in the code as below and then run the code the 500 error occurs.

```
# block/allow users by ip
    if(!empty($block_ips) || !empty($allowed_ips)){
    $htaccess_code .= "#Block-Allow users by IP\r\n";
    $htaccess_code .= "order allow,deny\r\n";
    }   
    if(!empty($block_ips)){
    $the_ips = explode(',',$block_ips);
        foreach($the_ips as $the_ip){ $htaccess_code .= "deny from ".trim($the_ip)."\r\n"; }
    }   
    if(!empty($allowed_ips)){
    $the_ips = explode(',',$allowed_ips);
        foreach($the_ips as $the_ip){ $htaccess_code .= "allow from ".trim($the_ip)."\r\n"; }
        }   
    $htaccess_code .= "allow from all\r\n";
    $htaccess_code .= "\r\n";
```

I am not sure where to go from here... any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Pete

Comment: try using the constant PHP_EOL insead of \r\n - this will give the platform specific end of line character sequence

Comment: You're blocking IP's, I think you just got some hack attacks, right? I had this problem also and there was an injected script that just added a random char to my htaccess to turn it off (what makes some sites vulnerable) - I recommend you to scan your htdocs/public_html - maybe this is related http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/28202

Comment: Have you tried using `PHP_EOL`instead of `"\r\n"`. Or remove `\r` and useonly `\n` (linux End Of Line)

Comment: @CodeBrauer there has been no attack but thank you for your input.

Comment: @Damien and PiX06 I have not tried PHP_EOL... not really sure what it is. checking now

Comment: From: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php: `PHP_EOL`
*The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 5.0.2*

Comment: I tried the `PHP_EOL` on the section of the script shown here to no avail but I think it is on the right path. I think I need to undo some work around I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002235/script-to-rewrite-htaccess-file-works-on-wamp-but-not-on-shared-host-on-the-net first and then use the `PHP_EOL` on the entire script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE RESOLVED:

While I am glad to have learned about `PHP_EOL` and did make the change on the entire script... it did not resolve the issue. The code was correct. The issue was in the IP addresses I tested with shown in the question.

Not being fully up to speed in IP Addresses I figured any comma separated 4 digits would do for a test... apparently not. I changed the test IPs to known IPs and the script worked fine.

Though a simple solution I thought it was worth sharing.

Thanks for all the input ... much appreciated

Pete